# Display ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Layer in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: arcgis-online, google-earth

Disclaimer: I am much less familiar with network/server/sharing nuances (much more experienced with desktop work).

I work for a nonprofit and am trying to map out where work is done. I have a large FGDB/HFL (hosted by ESRI in ArcGIS online) with a bunch of polygons of river basins (where the work is done). A lot of people we work with don't have ESRI accounts (and this will soon be a public layer).

My goal: have the polygons display in Google Earth Pro. While a conversion to a KML would be simple, the work territory is constantly changing, so I really need a link to share so that when I make updates, everyone can have the most updated version. I know Google Earth Pro has gotten more flexible in what it can handle and have tried adding the service URL for the HFL into the Add>Network Link option. Also tried creating a WFS. Neither working.

Any easy way to create a KML that will regularly update off a FGDB/HFL?

Comment: Was hoping GE would support GeoJSON?  Tried adding this as a Network Link but could not get it to work

Comment: http://services.arcgis.com/uCXeTVveQzP4IIcx/arcgis/rest/services/Portland_Coffee_Shops/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson

Comment: Could you use ArcGIS Earth which supports hosted feature layers? https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-earth/use/data-support.htm

Comment: @RussRoberts while it would technically work, everyone already has Google Earth and a familiar setup there. Would strongly prefer GE.